# How to integrate Fabric/Crashlytics in an shared extension

Tags: ios, swift, google-fabric, share-extension

I have integrated Fabric in my app, which is working fine .For the extension integration I have followed 2-3 links but nothing seems to be working.

Here is what I have tried:

**Added these lines in the Podfile:**

```
target 'MyApp share' do
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

**Added these properties in the Info.plist file:**

[image]

**In the viewcontroller of the shared extension, I have added these lines:**

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    }
```

Is there something I am missing for the integration?

Comment: Try this link it may help you out.https://github.com/ansonl/fabric-ios-extension

Comment: It is manual integration using frameworks , I am integration via pod

Comment: which error are you getting? share you console log.

Comment: I am not getting any errors , not able to see shared extension crashes on fabric dashboard

Comment: Does `Crashlytics` call `CrashlyticsDelegate` when a previous crash occurred on an app extension? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61801745/9636

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it started working , integrated it again and it started working. Not sure what went wrong