# Does Crashlytics call CrashlyticsDelegate when a previous crash occurred on an app extension?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I've integrated [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics) with my [iOS Today Widget Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27153383/9636) and [iOS iMessage Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40426903/9636). (Unfortunately, there's no official documentation for this.)

If one of my app extensions crashes, will `Crashlytics` call the `CrashlyticsDelegate` `-crashlytics:didDetectCrashDuringPreviousExecution:` callback within the app extension itself the next time app extension is run? Or will `Crashlytics` call the `CrashlyticsDelegate` on the main app itself? Or does `Crashlytics` not support `CrashlyticsDelegate` callbacks on app extensions?

Answer (score -3):

I would expect it to work as long as you are getting crashes from the app extension

Comment: Please add documentation to support your assertion.

Comment: @HeathBorders No documentation exists. I am from Firebase DevRel team and this info is directly from the engineers who works on iOS SDK. In general we haven’t focused on supporting App Extensions

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your answer! Please update your answer with that information, and please include an answer about whether the `CrashlyticsDelegate` callback runs within the main app or the app extension.

Comment: Claiming to work somewhere, and not providing any code or documentation is not an answer.